# MYSQL Select on two values one column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I need to select a row from my mysql table.

In the table there are two rows with one equal value.

```
TABLE
-----
articleId
keywordId
```

Now I need to select an article, that has keyword Id = 1, as well as keyword Id = 12.

Every link to a keyword has its own record.

How can I do one select query to know, if there is an article, that matches the two keywords?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *  
FROM tablename 
WHERE keywordId IN (1, 12) 
GROUP BY articleId 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b5f3/1)

Comment: SELECT ccdn_nid, COUNT( * ) 
FROM `ccdn_cmdt` 
WHERE `cmdt_tid` 
IN ( 1, 31584 ) 
GROUP BY `ccdn_nid` 
HAVING COUNT( * ) =2

I tryed this, but still getting the results that just have a record in 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: @user1955019 Check the demo.

Comment: Hey Saharsh, 

I still can't get it to work:

SELECT `ccdn_nid`
FROM `ccdn_cmdt`
WHERE `cmdt_tid`IN ( 1, 31641 ) 
GROUP BY `ccdn_nid`
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2

my table looks like this:
ccdn_nid int(11)     
cmdt_tid int(11)
ccdncmdt_outpid int(11)

Still getting one result results.

Comment: This is really strange, in Fiddle it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eff9f/2. But exactly the same query in our mysqlserver results in 50000 records...

Comment: FOund it! Because of more records in with KeywordId 1 but with a nother outputID, it counted as 2. Now with just one more WHERE it's fixd. Thanks Sasharsh! :)

Answer (score 4):

This is called [*Relation Division*](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). Here is one way to do so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE articleId IN
(
   SELECT articleId
   FROM tablename
   WHERE KeywordId IN (1, 2) 
   GROUP BY articleId
   HAVING COUNT(KeywordId ) = 2
);;
```

Comment: Will this query slow the db much down when used in hunderds of querys per minute?

Comment: @user1955019 It depends on how much rows do you have in that table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE `keywordId` = '1' AND `keywordId` = '12'
```

Comment: make sure the spelling 'TABLE' :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use subqueries for each keyword and join them

```
select k1.articleId from
(
    select articleId from TABLE where keywordId = 1
) k1
inner join
(
    select articleId from TABLE where keywordId = 12
) k2 on k1.articleId = k2.articleId
```

Depending on indexes and table size this can be more efficient than Group By

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE keywordId IN (1, 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ArticleId from Table where keywordId = 1
Intersect
select ArticleId from Table where KeywordId = 12
```

Comment: This doesn't exist or work. It might have worked in a previous version.