# SQL - AND statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `table1`:

[image]

I need to know who the `enum`  are who know HTML and ACCESS only. How could this be done?

I tried:

```
SELECT enum
FROM table1 
WHERE package="ACCESS" AND package="HTML"
```

But it returns no answer to me, and I'm certain that there should be...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, but.... I need that person who only knows HTML and ACCESS. If he knows one, its not enough. :/

Comment: What do you mean you want the `enum` with only `HTML` and `ACCESS`?  Do you only want to return the enum with both but nothing else?  If so, then none of your sample data would match.

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196134/mysql-select-on-two-values-one-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare values in different rows, making this a "set-within-sets" subquery.  Here is a solution using `group by` and `having`:

```
select `enum`
from table1
group by `enum`
having sum(package = 'ACCESS') > 0 and
       sum(package = 'HTML') > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause is counting the number of matches for each value.  Because you want both, the `> 0` ensures that the `enum` has at least one.

Note that I have put `enum` in backquotes.  `Enum` is a keyword in MySQL.  Even so, the backquotes are not needed, because it is one of a handful of such words that the parser allows with no backticks.  Still, it looks strange to see the word in this context, hence the backticks.

Comment: (so, it's not a reserved word !?!)

Answer (score 0):

You'd read the table and group by enum, then see if you got *all* desired package and *none* other for that enum.

```
select enum
from table1
group by enum
having sum(package in ('ACCESS', 'HTML')) = 2
and sum(package not in ('ACCESS', 'HTML')) = 0
and count(*) = 2;
```

One of the three conditions in the HAVING clause is superfluous. Remove whichever you like worst :-)

The query makes use of a MySQL feature where a true expression's value is 1 and a false expression's value is 0, so you can use SUM to count the true expressions.

Comment: Why are you including superfluous conditions?

Comment: @bluefeet: I wanted to show the options. It just doesn't matter which two of the three conditions to use. It's a matter of taste. But thinking about which to remove may even help understand what the expressions actually do :-)